# Get random Google+ user id

Tags: google-plus

I want to get random user from google+, but problem is to generete valid id.
What I know is :
 - id includes 21 numbers 
 - first number is "1"
 - second number is "0" or "1"

Problem is: numbers of active google+ users out of order.
I try to generete non stop id, but no one match active google+ id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a people.search request against the Google+ API using "random" keywords to get valid IDs.

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search

Just out of curiosity: what are you planning to do with those random IDs?

Comment: Thank you for answer, it is just for fun, I write test program that will show random google+ user by clicking "next" button. May be I add gender filter and +1 button.